# Javafx Loading xml Files Weird Error

Tags: xml, javafx, resources, filenotfoundexception, scenebuilder

I use IDEA Intellij.

I am having a problem where I can load certain xml files but others cannot.

For example I can load the gameFrame and sample fxml files.

[sample fxml loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcg72.png)

But not the startScreen or MainView fxml files

[MainView not being able to load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UZi2.png)

Some of the exceptions that pop up are:
InvocationTargetException
RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
javafx.fxml.LoadException
ClassNotFoundException: view.MainView

When I click on the source of the problem it directs me to the: startLayout = loader.load(); line and when I call it in the start method.

Rebuilding the program doesn't fix the problem. 
I saw some websites mention something about the resource files not being made? That might be it? If so can someone shed more light on it.

Here is the code:

```
package sample;

 import javafx.application.Application;
 import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
 import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main extends Application {

private Pane startLayout, gameFrame;
private Stage primaryStage;

//
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    this.primaryStage.setTitle("Ron");

    showStartScreen();
}
//

public void showStartScreen() throws IOException {

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("/view   /mainView.fxml"));
    startLayout = loader.load();
    Scene scene = new Scene(startLayout);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();


}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Error message:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
at  com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:18   2)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/Quy%20Phan/IdeaProjects/Ronv2/out/production/Ronv2/view/mainView.fxml:12

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:103)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:922)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
at sample.Main.showStartScreen(Main.java:42)
at sample.Main.start(Main.java:34)
at      com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:8   63)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: view.MainView
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:920)
... 18 more
Exception running application sample.Main

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Post the complete stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your stacktrace the exception occurs while loading `mainView.fxml` and is caused by something in line 12 of that file. If you could post the contents of the file I could answer more clearly.

This should probably be a comment, but I'm new here and don't have enough reputation... sorry.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <?import java.lang.*?>
    <?import java.util.*?>
    <?import javafx.scene.*?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

    <AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            fx:controller="view.MainView"
            prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0">

    </AnchorPane>

Comment: in view.MainView 

the MainView class is highlighted red

Comment: Oh!! I think I have figured it out now.

I need to create a controller class for the fxml file
and replace the:
fx:controller="view.MainView"
to 
fx:controller="view.MainViewController" 
or whatever I name the controller. Thanks!!

idk how you figured out something was wrong in my MainView fxml through that trace exception list but thank you

Comment: Oh yeah, you need a class to act as a controller to the window. 
Finding the cause for the exception is not the difficult, just look for the 'Caused by' lines, they detail the exception message. There are several of those, so find them one by one until you see a usable message. 

Just a note, you can edit your original question so you shouldn't post your code in a comment.